# I Julia, why is filter(isdir, readdir("data/") empty when readdir("data/") shows a dir?

Tags: julia

I'm having some issues using a `isdir` filter on `readdir` i Julia 1.7. Running the following:

```
println(readdir("data/"))
println(isdir("data/SST4Fj1_7d384.result"))
println(isdir("best_fit.csv"))
```

Prints (as expected):

```
["SST4Fj1_7d384.result", "best_fit.csv"]
true
false
```

But when running

```
println(filter(isdir, readdir("data/")))
```

it prints

```
String[]
```

Where I expected `["SST4Fj1_7d384.result"]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the full relative path in the list for the filter, not just subfolder name.

So this should be:

```
println(filter(isdir, readdir("data/", join=true)))
```